# mongoexport csv not exporting time

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongoexport

I am trying to export a collection to csv which has the following fields:
_id
number
name
price
pollingTime

I can see the polling time data when I open the collection in RoboMongo or try to access the collection through mongoshell, but when I export that into a CSV, the pollingTime field comes out blank.

Here's my mongoexport command:

```
mongoexport --db=itemDB --collection=itemprice1 --type=csv --fieldFile=fields.txt --out items.csv
```

I need to send this data to some non-tech business folks; any idea if I need to make any changes in the fields.txt. Fields.txt is like this:

> _id
>   number
>   name
>   totalPrice
>   pollingTimme

Comment: could you please update the question with sample document and fields.txt content ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies - I discovered immediately after while reviewing my question itself that I was making a mistake in the spelling of pollingTime field. I still want to keep the question and answer on StackOverflow so that others searching such a problem will try to look at their spellings :-)